# Подключение стилей в модуле Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Создал модуль и для него отдельный AppAsset, подключил стили и скрипты, но стили и скрипты не загружаются хотя если посмотреть исходный код страницы то все подключено. Вот код AppAsset

```
<?php

namespace frontend\modules\news\assets;

use yii\web\AssetBundle;

class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '/frontend/modules/news/web/';
    public $baseUrl = '/news';
    public $css = [
        'css/basis.css',
        'css/custom.css',
        'css/media.css',
        'css/magnific/styles.css',
        'css/slick/styles.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
        'js/pace.min.js',
        'js/imagesloaded.min.js',
        'js/magnific.min.js',
        'js/slick.min.js',
        'js/utilities.min.js',
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

Ресурсы находятся в директории frontend/modules/news/web/
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Что пишет в консоли?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Ну вот, из текста ошибки не правильно прописаны пути. Исправьте на нужные.

Answer (score 0):

Логично, что комплект ресурсов для модуля должен находиться где-то в модуле. Но из веба нет доступа в директорию модуля, поэтому файлы не будут подгружены на страницу. Базовый путь и базовый урл мы можем указывать в случае, если файлы доступны из веб. В других случаях необходимо указать источник, чтобы менеджер нашел необходимые файлы, скопировал их в доступную из веб директорию и подключил на страницу.

Примерная **структура модуля** у меня такая

[image: Структура модуля в Yii2]

В модуле `konkurs` есть комплекты ресурсов `assets`. В данном случае только один конкурс `fort`.

**Код ассета** обычно выглядит так. В $this->sourcePath достаточно указать текущую директорию.

```
class FortAsset extends AbstractAsset
{
public function init()
{
    $this->sourcePath = __DIR__;
    parent::init();
}

public $js = [
    'js/fort.js'
];

public $css = [
    'css/fort.css',
];

public $depends = [
    MainAsset::class,
];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за разъяснения))
Долго думал почему не подключаются стили. Хотя вроде написано все правильно. А потом осознал, что в модуле в корне не хватает папки **assets**  , как ее создал сразу стили подключились.

Класс описывал так:

```
public $sourcePath = '@app/modules/admin/web';
public $css = [];
public $js = [
   'js/admin.js',
];
```

А подключает Yii2 их как:

```
http://host.enot/assets/c9dc8856/js/admin.js
```

соответственно без пустой папки app/modules/admin/**assets** не отрабатывало подключение скриптов))))))